# Find the days in the month corresponding to the input number. Print Error if the input is not in a valid range

Tags: javascript, date

Find the days in the month corresponding to the input number. Print Error if the input is not in a valid range.

Sample Input :
8
Sample Output :
31

```
// Getting input via STDIN
const readline = require("readline");

const inp = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin
});

const userInput = [];

inp.on("line", (data) => {
  userInput.push(data);
});

inp.on("close", () => {


var arr = (userInput[0]).split(" ");


var getDaysInMonth = function(year) {
  // Here January is 1 based
  //Day 0 is the last day in the previous month
 return new Date(month, 0).getDate();
// Here January is 0 based
// return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
};
console.log(getDaysInMonth);



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getDaysInMonth function just needs a small tweak:

```js
const month = document.getElementById("month");
const numDays = document.getElementById("numDays");
month.addEventListener("change", e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  const answer = getDaysInMonth(e.target.value);
  console.log(answer);
  numDays.innerText = answer;
});

const thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();

function getDaysInMonth(month) {
  // Here January is 1 based
  // Day 0 is the last day in the previous month
  return new Date(thisYear, month, 0).getDate();
};
```

```html
<label for="month">Month (between 1 and 12):</label>
<input type="number" id="month" name="month" min="1" max="12">
<p>Number of Days: <span id="numDays"></span></p>
```